# How do I enable SSE2 from the command line

Tags: cmake, dlib

I'm compiling Dlib's Python Examples.

The compile script is:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../../tools/python 
cmake --build . --config Release --target install  
cd ..
```

How do I enable SSE2 from the command line? I tried adding the argument -USE_SSE2_INSTRUCTIONS=ON but got unknown argument error.

From Cmake cache file:

```
//Compile your program with SSE2 instructions
USE_SSE2_INSTRUCTIONS:BOOL=OFF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the -D.  So you have to say, cmake -DUSE_SSE2_INSTRUCTIONS=ON